# Expressing a set of Permutations as tuples

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, permutations

Say we want to construct a 5 letter word from the English alphabet $E=\{\mathsf a, \mathsf b, \dots,\mathsf z\}$, with repetition not allowed.

Suppose for the moment, that repetition *is* allowed. In that case, the set of words is simply $E^5$, whose size is $|E^5|=|E|^5=26^5$.

Now in the case where repetition is not allowed, then a word can be constructed in $^{26}\rm P_5 = 26 \times 25 \times 24 \times 23\times 22$ ways, a straightforward calculation.

My question is, is there an easy way to express the corresponding set of tuples we are enumerating, in terms of $E$? All I could think of was the cumbersome

$$\bigcup_{\ell_1\in E}\big(\bigcup_{\ell_2\in E\smallsetminus\{\ell_1\}}\big(\bigcup_{\ell_3\in E\smallsetminus\{\ell_1,\ell_2\}}\big(\bigcup_{\ell_4\in E\smallsetminus\{\ell_1,\ell_2,\ell_3\}}\{\ell_1\}\times\{\ell_2\}\times\{\ell_3\}\times\{\ell_4\}\times(E\smallsetminus\{\ell_1,\ell_2,\ell_3,\ell_4\})\big)\big)\big),$$
which seems needlessly complicated for a set which is so conceptually simple.

*Note*: I'd like something which makes use of set operations rather than set comprehension like $$\{(\ell_1,\ell_2,\ell_3,\ell_4,\ell_5):\text{$\ell_i\in E$ and $\ell_i\neq \ell_j$ for $i\neq j$}\},$$
which feels a bit like cheating.

Comment: Why does it feel like cheating? It a perfectly valid mathematical way to define a set, and it is much easier to comprehend than the complicated union you have written down.

Comment: @kccu Mostly because the complicated version can be broken down using rules about cardinality to arrive to the fact that its cardinality is $26(26-1)(26-2)(26-3)(26-4)$, whereas the other one can't.

Comment: The usual notation for and element of $e$ a set of $n$-tuples coming from a universe $E$ would be $e \in E^n$.   I would suggest that in analogy with falling powers, a good notation for a non-repeating n-tuple would be $$e \in E^\underline{n}$$.

Comment: The combinatorial proof of that set having $^{26}P_5$ objects is essentially its cardinality proof.

Comment: @palmpo I'm asking what is the most succinct way to express the set using operations.

Comment: @MarkFischler And more generally, $B^{\underline A}$ is a good notation for the set of injections from the set $A$ to the set $B$.

Answer (score 1):

The collection of $n$-tuples of a set $X$ without repetitions has the same cardinality as the set of injections from n to $X$, where n is your favorite $n$-element set. So $\mathrm{Inj}(\mathrm n,X)$ seems like a succinct notation, as is $X^\underline n$ in the comments.